# 301 Redirect all subdomain URL's to specific URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect, subdomain

My client had a bunch of location specific subdomain sites, but we've consolidated these into one site and created individual office pages. Can anyone help me go about 301 redirecting all location1.example.com URL's to example.com/location1 etc?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^location1\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/location1/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for this, almost there. This works for the base domain, but if I go to location1.example.com/about/ it'll go to example.com/about rather than example.com/location1. I assume this is as it's currently set up as an alias domain, but is there any way that the htaccess can catch this?

I just need all location subdomain addresses to go to the specific URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try in your .htaccess in the document root. This will convert any of your subdomains into subfolder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Not sure this is what I'm after but thanks! I'm specifically needing location1.example.com (and any /pages after this) to go to a specific URL, then location2.example.com to go to a different specific URL.

Comment: These rules are dynamic. So it's not tied to one subdomain. It should work for location1, location2, location3 etc.

Comment: So what happened with this?

Comment: Hi Panama Jack, sorry for the lack of reply. I'm unsure this will work if i've got doncaster.example.com as the subdomain but example.com/contact/doncaster-office/ as the new URL I want any doncaster.example.com subdomain URLs to redirect to?

Comment: If all the subdomains are going to a contact form, just change the rule accordingly. `RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.com/contact/%1-office/ [R=301,L]`